# Почему onmousemove даёт неправильные координаты?

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день, если вести курсор мыши вверх и влево, то координаты отображаются верно, если вести мышь вниз и вправо, то скрипт вставляет через раз неверные координаты, заведомо маленькие, допустим "(0,0); (1, 3)" и так далее.
Если отключить отрисовку "zone-select", то координаты передаются верно. Почему onmousemove передаёт неверные координаты?

```js
var rotate = 0;
var rFix = "45";
var zoom = "in";
var xScroll = 0;
var yScroll = 0;

function zoomFullSide(event) {
  var cellZoomIn = 55 * 50;
  var cellZoomOut = 11 * 50;
  if (zoom === "in") {
    $('.side-full-zoom').css({
      'height': cellZoomIn + 'px',
      'width': cellZoomIn + 'px',
      'cursor': 'zoom-out'
    });
    $('.side-full').scrollTop(yScroll * cellZoomIn / 550);
    $('.side-full').scrollLeft(xScroll * cellZoomIn / 550);
    zoom = "out";
  } else if (zoom === "out") {
    $('.side-full').css('overfow', 'hidden');
    $('.side-full-zoom').css({
      'height': cellZoomOut + 'px',
      'width': cellZoomOut + 'px',
      'cursor': 'zoom-in'
    });
    zoom = "in";
  }
}

function drawZoneSelect(event) {
  xScroll = Math.floor(event.offsetX / 10) * 10;
  yScroll = Math.floor(event.offsetY / 10) * 10;
  if (xScroll < 440 && yScroll < 440) {
    $('#log').text('y: ' + event.offsetY + ' x: ' + event.offsetX);
    $('.zone-select').css('top', event.offsetY);
    $('.zone-select').css('left', event.offsetX);
  }
}
```

```css
#modal-select-side {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#modal-select-side.animate {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#modal-select-side .side-full {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -275px;
  margin-top: -275px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  overflow: auto;
}

#modal-select-side .side-full .side-full-zoom {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  background: url(http://nn.by/img/w1500d4/photos/z_2015_10/cat-2un2u.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#modal-select-side .side-full #select-cell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#modal-select-side .side-full .zone-select {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: rgba(20, 180, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
}

#modal-select-side .side-full.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="modal-select-side">
  <div class="side-full">
    <div class="side-full-zoom" onmousemove="drawZoneSelect(event)" onclick="zoomFullSide(event)">
      <div class="zone-select"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение проблемы, поверх всего создаётся ещё один прозрачный элемент, на котором висит событие onmousemove, координаты, которого передаются на слой под ним **side-full-zoom**